# Navigation bar overlaping with content

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-position, navbar

I am trying to make my own portfolio website.

For some reason the navigation bar keeps overlapping with the rest of the contemt , even after adding margin to it and/or the other elements. The only way i am able to avoid this is by spamming line breaks.

Heres the html code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Quicksand&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.nav-bar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFDD93;
  transition: 1s;
}

.home-icon:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFDD93;
  transition: 1s;
}

ul {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

title {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Aman Nambisan</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <div class="nav-bar-div">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home home-icon" style="font-size:48px"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <p> hello </p>

  <script src="index.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what the live server looks like:
[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.nav-bar` has a fixed position, making it "flow" above your content. So a margin-bottom won't affect the elements that have a static position.

What you want to do is add a `padding-top` to your body element. You'll notice that the `.nav-bar` will slide down too. So you have to add a `top` position to that element. I commented the lines I've added in the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Quicksand&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 10em; /* added this line */
}

.nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; /* added this line */
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.nav-bar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFDD93;
  transition: 1s;
}

.home-icon:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFDD93;
  transition: 1s;
}

ul {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

title {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Aman Nambisan</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <div class="nav-bar-div">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home home-icon" style="font-size:48px"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <p> hello </p>

  <script src="index.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```